# Unable to input zero after decimal point in Android EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have an Android EditText which when a user puts a number, it edits the number and adds thousand separators using Decimal Format, but when one is inputting floating point numbers, i does not add zeros after the decimal point. so i can not input 1.000000008 because the zeros won't go on but other numbers do.
Is there any java DecimalFormat pattern that will allow a user to input a zero after the decimal point?
Here's the code for my EditText.

```
am = new TextWatcher(){
                 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                 }
                 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                     if (s.toString().contains(String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator())))
                        {
                            hasFractionalPart = true;
                        } else {
                            hasFractionalPart = false;
                        }
                 }
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    amount.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                    amount2.setText(s.toString());
                try {
                    int inilen, endlen;
                    inilen = amount.getText().length();

                    String v = s.toString().replace(String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator()), "");
                    Number n = df.parse(v);
                    value = Double.parseDouble(v);
                    int cp = amount.getSelectionStart();
                    if (hasFractionalPart) {
                        amount.setText(df.format(n));
                    } else {
                        amount.setText(dfnd.format(n));
                    }
                    endlen = amount.getText().length();
                    int sel = (cp + (endlen - inilen));
                    if (sel > 0 && sel <= amount.getText().length()) {
                        amount.setSelection(sel);
                    } else {
                        // place cursor at the end?
                        amount.setSelection(amount.getText().length() - 1);
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    // do nothing?
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // do nothing?
                }
               amount.addTextChangedListener(this);

               }
            };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rewrite**

**First,** when a decimal symbol is present let's count how many zeros will be trimmed off by the formatter. (If we find a non-zero character after the decimal, we'll reset our count. For example `1.00200` only has two trailing zeros.) In `onTextChanged()`:

```
int index = s.toString().indexOf(String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator()));
trailingZeroCount = 0;
if (index > -1)
{
    for (index++; index < s.length(); index++) {
        if (s.charAt(index) == '0')
            trailingZeroCount++;
        else {
            trailingZeroCount = 0;
        }
    }

    hasFractionalPart = true;
} else {
    hasFractionalPart = false;
}
```

**Next,** append the appropriate number of zero's back on to the formatted String. In `afterTextChanged()`:

```
if (hasFractionalPart) {
    StringBuilder trailingZeros = new StringBuilder();
    while (trailingZeroCount-- > 0)
        trailingZeros.append('0');
    amount.setText(df.format(n) + trailingZeros.toString());
} else {
    amount.setText(dfnd.format(n));
}
```

Note: You haven't posted the formats you use, so I've had to make a few assumptions, but this is easily adaptable.

Comment: thank you, but maybe i phrased the question wrong.....
my problem is that I can not type a zero after the decimal point.
so i can not write 1.0003 it just becomes 1.3
if i do what you are Suggesting it will always be 1.03 i want to be able to type in zeros after the decimal